# Azure script not running in CI

Tags: azure

```
- stage: windows_native
  displayName: Windows native
  jobs:
      - job: build_job
        pool:
            vmImage: "vs2017-win2016"
        steps:
            - task: NodeTool@0
              inputs:
                  failOnStderr: true
                  versionSpec: "10.16"
              displayName: "Install Node.js"
            - script: |
                  npm install
                  npx tsc --project tsconfig.production.json
                  npm run __prod__test__start_test
                  sdfsdfsdfsdf
              displayName: "Install, build and test"
```

Results in:

```
##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "d:\a\_temp\637dddda-9587-4798-814d-1f8bfcc3fb10.cmd""

> dtrace-provider@0.8.8 install D:\a\1\s\node_modules\dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js


D:\a\1\s\node_modules\dtrace-provider>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall D:\a\1\s\node_modules\core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js (‌ https:&#x2F;&#x2F;github.com&#x2F;zloirock&#x2F;core-js ‌) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!‌

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: ‌
&gt;‌ https:&#x2F;&#x2F;opencollective.com&#x2F;core-js ‌
&gt;‌ https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.patreon.com&#x2F;zloirock ‌

Also, the author of core-js (‌ https:&#x2F;&#x2F;github.com&#x2F;zloirock ‌) is looking for a good job -)‌


> nodemon@1.19.1 postinstall D:\a\1\s\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:‌
 &gt; ‌https:&#x2F;&#x2F;opencollective.com&#x2F;nodemon&#x2F;donate‌

npm WARN safedock-gateway@0.0.1 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 743 packages from 969 contributors and audited 3940 packages in 65.808s
found 2 critical severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
##[debug]Exit code: 0
##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.151.2\cmdline.ps1.
##[section]Finishing: Install, build and test
```

I was expecting it to fail due to my `sdfsdfsdfsdf` command. It doesn't seem to want to run the entire script. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `call` to the start of each line